# Cannot call java -classpath jna.jar <class>

Tags: java, c, jna

I used jna (java native access ) to compile and run C source in cmd environment. 
Firstly, I created two files cSource.c and Example.java and put them in C drive.My jdk version is 7 (64bit), and window 7 64bit

```
//cSource.c
#include <stdio.h>
void printPointOf(int n) {
    //printf("%p\n",&n);
}
```

and

```
//Example.java
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;

public class Example {
    public interface CSource extends Library {
        public void printPointOf(int n);
    }
    static public void main(String argv[]) {
        CSource cSrc = (CSource) Native.loadLibrary("csource", CSource.class);
        int n = 1;
        cSrc.printPointOf(n);
    }
}
```

Secondly, i opened cmd, then compiled and run
Step 0. `cd c:/`
Step 1. `gcc -o libcsourc.dylib -shared cSource.c`
Step 2. `javac -classpath jna.jar Example.java`
Step 3. `java -classpath jna.jar:. Example`

three first steps were successful, but step 3 my cmd caught an error:

```
Could not find or load main class
```

How can i solve the above error? Is my command in step 3 wrong? 
I consulted an article here : [Running C in Java with JNA](http://harunurhan.github.io/java/2014/02/20/run-c-in-java-with-jna/)

Comment: Doesn't solve the error, but a cast (`(void *)&n`) is needed for print addresses with `%p`

Comment: Did you tried 'java -classpath jna.jar Example'?

Comment: your `printPointOf(...)` function only prints the address of the local variable, or not?

Comment: @m88: the cmd still display :"Could not find or load main class".

Comment: @Manül : Even if i mark printf("%p\n",&n) as a comment. My cmd still display the above error.

Comment: you have a windows system? 'gcc -o libcsourc.dylib -shared cSource.c (if your os is Windows change .dylib to .dll)'

Comment: @m88: Thanks for your help. Combining to your advise, i fix my step that: 
Step 1: gcc -o cSource.dll -shared cSource.c
Step 3: java -classpath C:\;C:\jna.jar Example 
(file jna.rar locate in C drive, and i had consulted [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29#Setting_the_path_of_a_Jar_file))

Comment: In Windows, when you use the normal Windows command prompt, you must use `;` instead of `:` to separate entries in the classpath: `java -classpath jna.jar;. Example`